# CopyFileEx returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER even if the copy is successful on Win2012R2

Tags: winapi, windows-server-2012-r2

CopyFileEx with a following call to GetLastError returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER even if the copy is successful on Win2012R2 since around 2 months back (maybe from December 2015). On Windows XP till Windows 7 and Win 2k3 till Win2k8R2 this does not happen and GetLastError always returns 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS).

Is this expected behavior of this kind of Win32 API?
Do you have to add both result and GetLastError code be sure of the result?

This KB seems related to the problem but applying this patch does not alter the API behavior. There was probably another KB that caused the problem to appear but I have been unable to find it
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2963918

Documentation for GetLastError:

> Return value
>
> The return value is the **calling thread's last-error code.**
>
> The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that
>   sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function
>   sets the last-error code. Most functions that set the thread's
>   last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also
>   set the last-error code when they succeed. **If the function is not
>   documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this
>   function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set;**
>   some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do
>   not.

Comment: A posibility would be that the ProgressCallBackRoutine is setting an error. But I imagine that this is called on another thread? (and thus not visible from the calling thread?) Or is the callback on the current thread and the copy operation on another? Or are both the same? (then a lengthy UI-operation in the callback might slow things down)

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx) tells you to call `GetLastError` on failure only. Calling it after `CopyFileEx` successfully returned does not produce a well defined value. Your code relies on unspecified behavior, and just got unlucky on one system. It is buggy, and you need to fix it. There is nothing wrong with the API.

Comment: @IInspectable CopyFileEx does not own the result of the threads LastErrorCode. Any call on the same thread can set it on errors. Documentations for CopyFileEx implies that LastErrorCode is not touched if successful, only set if it fails. This implies that either something internally in CopyFileEx fails or my own Callback fails(if it is on the same thread).

Comment: No, the documentation does not state that at all.

Comment: Success and failure of `CopyFileEx` is reported by its return value. In case the call fails you can call `GetLastError` to gather additional information. The documentation makes no mention and does not imply anything about the last error code in case the call succeeds. You are reading something into the documentation that isn't there. Your code has a bug. Fix it.

Comment: Why does everyone keep repeating that I have a bug in my code that needs fixing? I never mentioned that I have code dependent on this?

Comment: I guess we can't fathom why this question hasn't been wrapped up now. It has been answered. We are struggling to see what you are still stuck on.

Comment: At this point I'm guessing you'd like to see an answer stating which update (or other change) introduced the change you describe, and perhaps why.  Microsoft might know, or another vendor if it happens that it was introduced by third-party software, but it's unlikely that any of the regulars here would have noticed the change or cared enough if they did notice to investigate in any detail.  In any case, since the change doesn't affect properly-written software, the cause and/or motivation are outside of the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Harry Johnston You are absolutely right! The assumption is that the original problem with CopyFileEx originated from someone that regulars Stackoverflow. People with view of the code is usually under NDA so they cant tell. But MSFT people or the person reporting the error might be allowed. My original code has been in production around 10 years and it is only logging last error code from all API calls (causing an annoyance in my logs, it might also be considered overly cautious) but it does not depend on the error code and works as intended otherwise.

Comment: @Harry Johnston I am also a bit worrying that there are more problems with CopyFileEx (my code monitors a backup system that uses CopyFileEx) on Win2k12. It might be a simple slip up that the final part of the code is setting "SetLastError(87)" no matter what. But it could also mean that they back patched code from Window 10 (or a coming server edition) and used a coming internal API that is not supported on Win2k12 causing the "Invalid parameter". And I have not yet tested with a real error to check if a real error overwrites the "87" error if it happens after the last callback.

Comment: Just so long as you realize that this isn't a Microsoft site.

Comment: @Harry Off course. My intention is to leave this question open for a while and see if someone has something interesting to pitch in. Then I will accept an answer. (Davids answer is right in describing the proper API handling so for the community I will consider it as the answer if nothing else pops up)

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa363852.aspx):

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error
>   information call GetLastError.

In other words, if the function succeeds, you are not expected to call `GetLastError`, and no promise is made about what will be returned if you do.

So, you are ascribing meaning to the value returned by `GetLastError` where no meaning should be ascribed.

This is a common pattern in Win32. A great many functions are similar. The value returned by `GetLastError` is only meaningful in the event that the return value of the function indicates failure. That is not a universal rule though, so you do need to check the documentation on a function by function basis.

The typical form of a call to such a Win32 function looks like this:

```
if (CopyFileEx(...))
{
    // function call succeeded, continue
}
else
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    // do something with err
}
```

Note that `GetLastError` is only called if the function indicates failure through its return value.

Comment: When I read the documentation for GetLastError it states that some functions use it to set 0 for success. And as you say the documentation for CopyFileEx does not state that it will set ERROR_SUCCESS for successfull copy. But in no documentation does it say that CopyFileEx will set last error to an actual Error code if it does NOT fail. Unless Microsft coded a bug in their internal code which internally gets an error (its per thread). That MS would call something with an invalid parameter internall is even worse in my book if that is what is implied?

Comment: When CopeFileEx succeeds the last error code's value is undefined.

Comment: Not that I am aware of? If CopyFileEx succeedes it does not set last error at all. There is no junk value for last error and it cannot be undefined since it belongs to the calling thread. If the caller (me) did not set it and it has been changed from before and after the call to CopyFileEx then another API call inside CopyFileEx has set it to an error code.

Comment: You've got that wrong. You can't infer any meaning from the error code when this function succeeds. I've said that many times now. There's nothing more to say.

Comment: David is absolutely right, there is no guarantee that CopyFile won't have set the last error code to a nonzero value if it succeeds.  For example, CopyFile might use another function internally which sometimes fails in a way that doesn't prevent CopyFile from succeeding.  (Something like "OK, let's call the function that does a really-fast-copy.  That didn't work?  Oh, never mind, we'll call the function that does a slow copy.  That worked?  Great., we're done.")

Comment: @Harry You are absolutely right on certain cases, like what you said and maybe an error code like "File missing" (if it uses some API to check the destination). But in the case of the error in the question the error code is "ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER ". As far as I know that can only be programming error. If it internally calls "ReallyFastCopy" it should not call it with the wrong parameter.

Comment: The programming error is in your code where you infer meaning to the error code when no meaning should be inferred.